# about orthogonal complement

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, optimization

Im reading a chapter talking about orthogonal complement of dual space in optimization by vector space. I have captured something confusing as following:
[image]

I cannot understand some parts of the proof of Theorem1:

1. Why the author will define the linear functional as the form of f(αx + m) equal to α instead of equaling to any other constant? I mean why the right side of equation should be the same to the α in αx?
2. since the linear functional as the form of f(αx + m) = α, how could it become the  f(x + m) = 1 in the following equation:

[image],

which means that α = 1? that's really confusing me a lot.

3. Does f vanishes on M mean f equals to 0 on subspace M? How to get it?

P.S. definition of orthogonal complement is defined as following:
[image]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If in this book $\;^\perp U\;$ is the orthogonal complement of $\;U\;$ , I wonder what then is $\;U^\perp\;$ ...?

Comment: It looks like a notion defined on the dual, so in a sense it is "pre-dual". The orthogonal of $U$ lies in $X^{**}$, while $\;^\perp U\;$ lies in $X$.

Comment: @DonAntonio: I have attached the definition of orthogonal complement superscripting on right side

Comment: @MartinArgerami: I have attached the definition of orthogonal complement superscripting on right side.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: Thanks for ur reply. It does make a little sense. for question1, why αx + m should -> α instead of ->, for example, 2 or 3 or something else that belongs to scalar field? For question2:|| f || = sup(|| f(αx + m) || / || αx + m ||) for m belongs to M and then why can we say that || f || can achieve its supreme at α = 1 not 2 or 3 or any other real number? For question3: Does make great sense! I really appreciate u.

Comment: Maybe you are not understanding the definition of $f$: $f(x+m)=1$, $f(2x+m)=2$, $f(\pi x+m)=\pi$, $f(\sqrt2 x+m)=\sqrt2$, $f(-x+m)=-1$, etc. Your question is right regarding 2: I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: Yes. im a newbie to functional analysis. I see ur edit and reconfirm that since m belong to M, then, multiplied by scalar 1/a, that is m/a will still belong to M, right?

Comment: Yes. More precisely, $M=\{m:\ m\in M\}=\{m/\alpha:\ m\in M\}$, since $M$ is a subspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The author *defines* the functional $f$. Since $x$ and $m$ are linearly independent, the assignment $\alpha x+m\mapsto\alpha$ is well-defined.
2. This is basically the same as $1$. The functional maps any vector of the form $\alpha x+m$ to $\alpha$. When in particular $\alpha=1$, you get $f(x+m)=1$. Then
   $$
   \|f\|=\sup_{\alpha\in\mathbb C,\ m\in M}\,\frac{|f(\alpha x+m)|}{\|\alpha x+m\|}=\sup_{\alpha\in\mathbb C,\ m\in M}\,\frac{|\alpha|\,|f( x+m/\alpha)|}{|\alpha|\,\|x+m/\alpha\|}=\sup_{\alpha\in\mathbb C,\ m\in M}\,\frac{|f( x+m/\alpha)|}{\|x+m/\alpha\|}=\sup_{\alpha\in\mathbb C,\ m\in M}\,\frac{|f( x+m)|}{\|x+m\|}=\sup_{m\in M}\,\frac{|f( x+m)|}{\|x+m\|}.
   $$
3. The functional $f$ vanishes on $M$ by definition: for any $m\in M$, $f(m)=f(0\,x+m)=0$.